# Only half of my object is immutable - can I mark it that way?

Tags: groovy

I have an groovy class - half of its properties are always immutable (and set during construction), the other half mutable.

Is there any way I can mark it as such in Groovy?

Comment: No, a half mutable object is mutable. Why not extract the immutable half out into an immutable object and have your mutable object delegate to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no shades of grey when it comes to mutability or immutability.

It's a bit like food:  *"I have a hamburger that's half inedible and half edible..."*

One option would be to extract your immutable portion to an Immutable class and then delegate to that in your mutable portion, ie:

```
import groovy.transform.*

@Immutable
class Point {
    int x, y
}

@Canonical
class Pixel {
    int color
    @Delegate Point point
}

Pixel p = new Pixel( 0xFF0000, new Point( 10, 10 ) )
assert p == new Pixel( 0xFF0000, new Point( 10, 10 ) )

// Change the mutable color
p.color = 0x00FF00
assert p == new Pixel( 0x00FF00, new Point( 10, 10 ) )

// Change the point (can be done as Pixel is mutable)
p.point = new Point( 10, 20 )
assert p == new Pixel( 0x00FF00, new Point( 10, 20 ) )

// Cannot change the Point properties
try {
    p.point.x = 20
    assert false
}
catch( e ) {
    assert e.class == ReadOnlyPropertyException
}
```

Or, if it's possible to make the whole thing Immutable, you could use the `copyWith` method to generate new Pixels:

```
import groovy.transform.*

@Immutable
class Point {
    int x, y
}

@Immutable( copyWith=true )
class Pixel {
    int color
    @Delegate Point point
}

Pixel p = new Pixel( 0xFF0000, new Point( 10, 10 ) )
assert p == new Pixel( 0xFF0000, new Point( 10, 10 ) )

// Make a new copy with a new color
p = p.copyWith( color:0x00FF00 )
assert p == new Pixel( 0x00FF00, new Point( 10, 10 ) )

// Make a new copy with a new point
p = p.copyWith( point:new Point( 10, 20 ) )
assert p == new Pixel( 0x00FF00, new Point( 10, 20 ) )

// Cannot change the Point properties directly
try { p.point.x = 20 ; assert false }
catch( e ) { assert e.class == ReadOnlyPropertyException }

// or
try { p.color = 0x0000FF ; assert false }
catch( e ) { assert e.class == ReadOnlyPropertyException }
```